# Stirling number recursion formula

Tags: combinatorics

Let $S\left( {n,r} \right) = r \times S\left( {n - 1,r} \right) + S\left( {n - 1,r - 1} \right)$ where $S\left( {n,r} \right)$ represent the distribution of $n$ distinct ball into $r$ identical bins providing that no bins remain empty.

How do we prove it by a simple test case.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I am not able to understand the formula as I am new to this portion of P&C but what I understood is distribution of n distinct ball into r distinct non-empty bin is equivalent to sum of distribution of n-1 distinct ball into r distinct ball times r and n-1 distinct bin into r-1 non-empty distinct box

Comment: Your question should be "Looking for a combinatorial explanation for the Stirling formula" because "simple test case" is meaningless in this context.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really want to prove the recurrence relationship through a test case mechanically, you want to understand why the formula works !

- A **particular** ball can either be alone in a cell, or along with others
- If it is alone, the remaining $(r-1)$ cells must be filled by $(n-1)$ balls, $\Rightarrow S(n-1,r-1)$
- If it is with other(s), $r$ cells are already filled with $(n-1)$ balls, and the **particular** ball can go to any of the $r$ cells, $\Rightarrow r*S(n-1,r)$
- Add the two  to get the recurrence relationship